# Access the latitude,longitude values after invoking the requestLocationUpdates in the service

Tags: android

I have TrackingService component to track the location of the buses in my city based on Crowdsourcing. The TrackingService is operating in the background, then the data is transmitted to the server. The background TrackingService is started in the MainActivity  when the app launches.

I have another component to access the bus's location. This component is started when the user selects the desired bus route/s in the MainActivity (as a filter). then, The the alarmManager starts with the intentService class to retrieve the data from the server to the Map activity.

Everything works for me but I want to display the user current location beside the bus location when the user click the button in the MainActivity. Thats means I have to retrieve the calculated `pLat, pLong` in the `onLocationChanged()` in `TrackingService` class (TrackingService component) to the `Map` activity  (accessing component) when the user clickes the button in the MainActivity.

Currently I am doing it with the aid of `LocalBroadcastManager` but in this case the current location is being display only after the `lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,this);` was invoked which leads to the delay in the visualization of the user current location which is not user-friendly.

Is there any way to store the last values of the `pLat,pLong` for a long time to get them when the user clicks the button in the MainActivity?

**TrackingService class:**

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements
        LocationListener {
    public double pLong;
    public double pLat;
    ...
        @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        detectLocation();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private void detectLocation() {
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30 * 1000, 0,
                this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
        pLong = location.getLongitude();
        pLat = location.getLatitude();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Map.RECEIVE_latLng);
        intent.putExtra("location",location);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
           .....

     }  

}
```

**Map activity:**

```
    public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback   {
   public static final String RECEIVE_latLng = "com.bustracker.RECEIVE_latLng";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

    }
        @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();        
    LocalBroadcastManager bManager =    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(RECEIVE_latLng);
    bManager.registerReceiver(bReceiver, intentFilter);
}

    private BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_latLng)) {
                              Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra("location");
             double lng = location.getLongitude();
             double lat = location.getLatitude();
             LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
             MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title("My Location")
                        .position(ll);
             myLocatMarker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
            }
          }
        };      
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last location in the onConnected method of the location services api. See here in the developer documentation : https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Or else you can store the user's last location in the Shared preferences and retrieve that when you start your activity

Comment: I am trying to get the last known location by using google api but I dont know where have I to delare `Location mLastLocation` in the `onConnected()` since I am getting `mLastLocation cannot be resolved to a variable`?

Comment: You either have not declared mLastLocation as a variable or it is out of scope of the method.. Declare mLastLocation at the very top where you have declared plong,plat